# Extrusion/Bevel of Path with many points

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm trying to visualize data in blender and the measurements often have many datapoints close to each other.
Using a NURBS curve and a bevel to make the curve have thickness, it struggles with noisy data. Here, the surface is turned into itself and looks strange. I'd like to end up with similar results to the 2D plot provided. I would assume the problem is with the very fast changes in tangent/normals directions. Is there a way to achieve similar "lines", like I have in the 2D version, where spikes are shown, but the outer surface is combined?

[image] [image]

Comment: You could try smoothing? And/or re-meshing? Maybe you could share a typical data-set with us on https://blend-exchange.com/, and  typical target results (hand-made if necessary)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found a way to present the line as "flat", by using an emittent shader in the material. This way, irrespective of the camera angle, the line looks like a "plane" and looks very similar to the drawing, instead of a 3D object. This way, the self-intersections of the path looks fine.